# PLSQL - dbms_network_acl_admin.create_acl error

Tags: xml, oracle, rest, http, plsql

I'm dealing with this problem for hours...
I've researched and tried on my own, but nothing seems to help.

So I was running this code

```
begin
dbms_network_acl_admin.create_acl(
     acl => 'www.xml',
     description => 'www ACL',
     principal => 'SYS',
     is_grant => true,
     privilege => 'connect'
 );

 dbms_network_acl_admin.assign_acl(
     acl => 'www.xml',
     host => '*',
     lower_port => 80
 );
 end;
```

and I keep getting this error:

> Error report -
>   ORA-31024: Parser initialization failed with LPX-266 error
>   while parsing a stream to XOB
>   ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN", line 252
>   ORA-06512: at line 2
>   31024. 00000 -  "Parser initialization failed with LPX-%s error\nwhile %s"
>   *Cause:    Error occurred while initializing a parser.
>   *Action:   Contact Oracle Support Services.

How can I resolve it?

Comment: That is an internal error, and you need to contact oracle support, as it is mentioned.

Comment: Probably not a very good advice, but - did you try to reboot the database server? Hopefully, that would be your PC so no problem. Otherwise, huh ... think twice.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with XDB (XML database). (XOB is something like DOM object but with better memory optimization).

Try to run this. i'm 99% sure that it fail.

```
SELECT 
   xmlserialize( document object_value)
FROM 
   xdb.xs$securityclass
WHERE 
   EXTRACTVALUE(object_value, '/securityClass/@targetNamespace')='http://xmlns.oracle.com/plsql'
AND
   EXTRACTVALUE(object_value, '/securityClass/@name')='network'
/
```

Solutions.

1) If possible reinstall db.
2) Or reinstall XDB http://www.oracle-wiki.net/startdocshowtoinstallxmldb